# Using postgres percentile function with negative numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, statistics, aggregate-functions

I have a table of containing records with negative numbers:

| ID | Location | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paris | -1 |
| 2 | London | -2 |
| 3 | Berlin | -3 |
| 4 | Moscow | -4 |
| 5 | Rome | -5 |
| 6 | Warsaw | -6 |
| 7 | Madrid | -7 |
| 8 | Amsterdam | -8 |
| 9 | Milan | -9 |
| 10 | Zurich | -10 |

*(my actual records and values are more numerous and more complex, but this should help illustrate the issue)*

I want to get the **minimum**, **first quartile**, **median**, **third quartile**, **maximum** of the temperature values, **but in reverse**.

For instance, in my example I would have:

| Aggregate | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Minimum | -1 |
| First quartile | -2.5 |
| Median | -5 |
| Third quartile | -7.5 |
| Maximum | -10 |

The problem as I see it is that my numbers are negative. So when I run:

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "city_temperatures"."temperature") AS percentile_temperature FROM "city_temperatures"
```

I actually get the value third quartile as opposed to the first quartile.

What's the best way to handle negative numbers in a query like this?

Comment: Please *always* disclose the version of Postgres in use. Also, a fiddle would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `DESC` to `ORDER BY`?

```
SELECT percentile_cont(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.temperature DESC) AS pct_temp
FROM city_temperatures t;
```

You might get all of it as array in a single calls with:

```
SELECT percentile_cont('{0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1}'::float8[])
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.temperature DESC) AS pct_temps
FROM city_temperatures t;
```

Comment: Thanks @erwin , but I've just realised: Am I being really stupid? Won't 0.75 in the negative numbers be exactly the same as 0.25 in the reversed order?

Comment: @BetjaminRichards Sure. You can invert the percentile, or the sort order, same result.